# stdout redirection doesn't work when using nohup and logging out of ssh

Tags: bash, ssh, io-redirection, nohup

I ran into a weird problem when trying to run nohup over an SSH connection. It seems like the stdout redirection isn't working, or something else fails.

Here's the sequence of test commands I did:

Connected to the remote host, create a file test.sh with two lines:

```
sleep 60
echo "Hello!"
```

Then I run `nohup bash test.sh > out.txt &`, disconnect and reconnect to host. I know the process didn't terminate because I can see the process running with `ps` (after reconnecting within 60 seconds of running the script). After waiting for the script to finish, I find that out.txt is empty.

The redirection works fine if I don't disconnect in-between. Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. -- You say you can see the process running with `ps` after reconnecting. That would indicate the `echo "Hello!"` hasn't been executed yet...?!? I *assume* you waited until the `sleep 60` expired after the `ps` check, *then* looked for `out.txt`. Perhaps you are confused about the directory `out.txt` should appear in. Have you tried an absolute path (`/home/miatrix/out.txt`) to be sure about the location?

Comment: Running this script works just fine for me. As @DevSolar says, the problem may be in paths or permissions to write a file locally. You should not see the process running in `ps` after 60 seconds.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I reconnect before 60 seconds, so the sleep command should still be running. I run `ps` immediately, and indeed I see the script still running. Then I wait until I no longer see the script in `ps`, and examine `out.txt`. I don't see why the directory would change...in fact, nohup immediately creates out.txt (blank) when you call it. I'm suspecting it's something peculiar to my host, maybe?

Comment: this is probably stupid, but have you looked in $HOME/nohup.out for any errors, or to be sure it is not being redirected there?

Comment: My home directory is unchanged. There are no nohup.out or out.txt files.

Comment: It is working fine for me too. Just for debug, try to redirect the StdErr too and print the PID of the process when spawning:
`nohup bash test.sh 1> $HOME/out.txt 2> $HOME/err.txt | echo $! &`

Comment: What is the OS version, bash shell version on your system?

Comment: Scientific Linux CERN SLC release 6.9 (Carbon), GNU bash version 4.1.2(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu). @CristiánRamón-Cortés both files are still empty.

Comment: Although it works for me like you stated, can you try removing the bash command and making the file executable? `chmod +x test.sh ; nohup ./test.sh 1> $HOME/out.txt 2> $HOME/err.txt &`

Comment: Both files are still empty. I also tried with adding the shebang `#!/bin/bash` but that didn't change anything. I'm curious if it might have to do with some permission settings that change once I logout. I've once ran a long-running command on the same host using `screen`, logging out, and coming back to find that the program failed because it didn't have authorization to create and write a file, which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: If the script is indeed creating an empty `out.txt` file, then permissions shouldn't be an issue. Perhaps there is not enough free space on disk for a 6 byte Hello!

Comment: There's definitely enough free space...I can write the lines and save it.